# Issues with the "setdiff" command in R

Tags: r, excel

I have a questions regarding an issue I have been having with the "setdiff" command in R.

I have loaded 2 excel files into R by using the following commands:

```
data.x<- read_excel("c:/Users/User/Dropbox/excel til R/X.xlsx", col_names=FALSE)
data.y<- read_excel("c:/Users/User/Dropbox/excel til R/Y.xlsx", col_names=FALSE)
```

I then proceed to use the following command:

```
setdiff(data.y, data.x)
```

Here I hoped it would just tell me what variables was absent in "data.x". But instead it just shows me the data that is present in "data.y", as if I simply used the command: "data.y".

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `setdiff` only works on two vectors not on tables (in response to comment of @Gregor, it works on tables but I guess not as you - or me - assumed it works). How does your data look like, I guess you have several columns. Hence, you might feed the first column of each table to `setdiff`.

Comment: Maybe you wanted `setdiff(colnames(data.y),colnames(data.x))` instead?

Comment: @ManuelBickel `setdiff` works fine on data frames, e.g., `setdiff(mtcars, mtcars[-1])`. It will do default comparisons as row-wise, and throw an error if there are different columns. Not sure what you're expecting/what you want.

Comment: You are right, just edited my comment. Thanks.

Comment: I tried: setdiff(colnames(data.y),colnames(data.x))                                                  .                                                                                                                  
.But it just said: character(0)

Comment: ...although specifying `col_names = FALSE` means that R will likely just name the columns with defaults like `X1`, `X2`, etc for both files.

Comment: Would it be possible to load the tables in excel as vectors in R?

Comment: `character(0)` simply means there is no column name in `data.y` that is not in `data.x`.

Comment: It's just that when I check for differences between the two files I find several. That's why I can't understand the "character (0)" response.

Comment: To be honest, you seem very unclear about the difference between there being differences in the _column names_ versus there being differences in the _data_. None of this is resolvable without specific examples of data frames that we can compare ourselves.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. And yes, I my be a bit unclear about it. That's why I'm thankfull that you guys are willing to help me.                                             .Here are parts of the two sets of data:                                             data.x: 010238-23, 239482-45, 207586-56, 235684-93, 647385-46,                                                                                                                                                                                                                        .data.y: 010238-23, 239482-45, 207586-56, 235684-93, 475693-92,

Comment: they are all placed in seperate columns

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dplyr::setdiff()` instead of just `setdiff()`.
There is another `setdiff()` function in base R.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the files noted in your question I'll present examples using

```
mtcars_1 <- mtcars[-1, ][, -1]
mtcars_2 <- mtcars[-2, ][, -2]

# common column names
intersect(names(mtcars_1), names(mtcars_2))

# columns names only in mtcars_0 and not in mtcars_2
setdiff(names(mtcars_1), names(mtcars_2))

# columns only in mtcars_2 and not in mtcars_1 
setdiff(names(mtcars_2), names(mtcars_1))
```

To get the varaibles absent in `data.x` with respect to `data.y` you would use
`setdiff(data.y, data.x)`

If you are looking for the *rows* of `data.x` that are not in `data.y` consider using the
`anti_join` and/or `semi_join` functions form the [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr) package

> ```
> ‘semi_join()’ return all rows from ‘x’ where there are matching
>      values in ‘y’, keeping just columns from ‘x’.
>
>      A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner join
>      will return one row of ‘x’ for each matching row of ‘y’, where a
>      semi join will never duplicate rows of ‘x’.
>
> ‘anti_join()’ return all rows from ‘x’ where there are not matching
>      values in ‘y’, keeping just columns from ‘x’.
> ```

```
dplyr::semi_join(mtcars_1, mtcars_2)
dplyr::semi_join(mtcars_2, mtcars_1)

dplyr::anti_join(mtcars_1, mtcars_2)
#   cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

dplyr::anti_join(mtcars_2, mtcars_1)
#   mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  21  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
```